# Sending a Solr query url in SolrNet

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

I have a certain url representing a Solr request which I would like to send with SolrNet. The url contains the request handler name and some other parameters such as a `stream.url`. How do I generate the request using SolrNet and send it to Solr?

Please illustrate the way to do it with a concrete request. For example: `http://localhost:8983/solr/mlt?stream.url=http://lucene.apache.org/solr/&mlt.fl=manu,cat&mlt.interestingTerms=list&mlt.mintf=0`. Namely, how do I specify in C# code which request handler to use, how do I instantiate all the GET parameters in the above url, and finally, how do I execute the query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the [SolrNet Wiki Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki), specifically the following:

- [Mapping](https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Mapping)
- [Initialization](https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Initialization)
- [Querying](https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Querying)
- [More Like This](https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/MoreLikeThis)

For additional parameters that are not included directly in SolrNet, see the "Additional Parameters" section at the Querying link above.

Please look through this information and come back if you have any issues setting things up or executing a query.